# JavaScript によりフリーハンドで描画させたい

Tags: javascript, html5, html5-canvas

JavasSriptで手書き入力を実現させたいのですが、中々いいサンプルがありません。

色の選択、線の太さ等設定は必要ありません。
単純にかければいいだけです。

サンプルページ等あれば教えて下さい。
宜しくお願いします。

Comment: "ｊavascript 手書き" で検索してトップに出てくる
[Ajax を使った手書き文字認識](http://chasen.org/~taku/software/ajax/hwr/)
ではどうでしょうか。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

お絵かきツール的なものだと判断しました。
「かければいいだけ」であることを考えて最小限のコードを書くと次のようになります。

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
    e.buttons === 1 && canvas.getContext("2d").fillRect(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 5, 5);
});
```

```html
<canvas/>
```